# Script tag in HTML making an odd symbol

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making an HTML site and I have some jQuery code in it. Of course, I need to have a script tag in the head for this to be possible. However, when I do this, it renders an odd symbol in the actual layout. Here's the tag snippet:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌
```

And here's the symbol that's rendering: `â€Œ`

What's going on here? Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Here's a screenshot of the of the page.
[image: Screenshot]

Edit 2: Here's a screenshot of the of the source.
[image: Screenshot 2]

Here's the actual head in the HTML file:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var trigger = $('.nav-trigger')
                var menu = $('#mmenu')
                var body = $('body')

                trigger.click(function() {  
                    if (trigger.is(":checked")) {
                        var i = 0;
                        setInterval(function() {
                            if(i<285) {
                                i+=5;
                                var left = i + 'px';
                                menu.css('margin-left', left);
                            }
                        }, 1);
                        body.css('overflow', 'hidden')
                    } else {
                        var i = 285;
                        setInterval(function() {
                            if(i>0) {
                                i-=5;
                                var left = i + 'px';
                                menu.css('margin-left', left);
                            }
                        }, 1);
                        body.css('overflow', 'auto')
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
```

Comment: Looks like a 3 byte character to me, possibly UTF-8. It's very unlikely that the script tag is the problem. Rather, you inadvertently rendered a character the browser can't display. Can we look at the source somewhere? Or can you post a screen shot?

Comment: @MaxLeske The issue goes away when the script tag is removed, so I'm not sure. I'll post a screenshot, one sec.

Comment: Can you open the source (right click -> view source)? Can you post the `<head>` section?

Comment: @MaxLeske I'll post a picture of the source and paste the head in the actual HTML file.

Comment: Try to upload it to online service like Jsfiddle or Codepen, test it there if the same problem is appear, you can update your question with the link, that's will be clearer to solve

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the file is encoded with ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, or the like, and not actually saved as a UTF-8. So its got a BOM at the start which is the first few bytes of the file which specifies the encoding - You can see it in an Hex Editor but you're unlikely to see it in notepad or anything else - even though you think of the file a just plain old text.

BOM's don't typically display in editors - but you can see them in RAW data.

â€Œ is in fact:

```
â => Unicode 0xe2   => CP-1252 0xe2
€ => Unicode 0x20ac => CP-1252 0x80
Œ => Unicode 0x153  => CP-1252 0x9c
```

So all you need to do is load the offending file (probably your HTML) into an Editor like Sublime, Notepad++  and then save it back to disc with encoding set as UTF8 rather than windows-1252 as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

somewhere in the `<head>` tag

Comment: Text isn't appearing, but there's still a space where it was there.

Comment: Wait, can't you just delete that? Why is it in your head? Above the script that you copied, the script you link, at the end of it.

Comment: I know what you mean, but that only shows up in the browser. When I pull it up in Chrome, those characters show up, but it's not actually like that in the code.

Comment: Try deleting all the whitespace in the code between the end of the script (where the text renders) and start of the next one. The character is in there hidden somewhere. I'm assuming you copied that link from the web somewhere and it might have crept in there.

Comment: Deleted the whitespace but the text still persists.

Comment: `body { margin-top: -1em; }` might fix the issue, but that is pretty sketchy

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing haha. Thanks for the help!